# R: How to create a new column in a data frame with "countif" values from another data frame?

Tags: r

I have one dataframe (df1) that looks as follows. It indicates years when a company was active in a specific market.

```
Company  Country  Year
A        Austria  2010
A        Germany  2010
A        Austria  2011
B        Italy    2010
```

I now have a second dataframe (df2) that looks as follows. It lists all investments of a company in a country at a given time, by investment type as dummy variabes.

```
Company  Country  Year  JointVenture  M&A  Greenfield
A        Austria  2010  1             0    0
A        Austria  2010  0             1    0
A        Austria  2010  1             0    0
...
```

My question now is as follows: I want to **add a new column to df1**, including the **"countif"** of each investment type as indicated in df2. For instance, new df1:

```
Company  Country  Year  Count.JointVenture  Count.M&A  Count.Greenfield
A        Austria  2010  2                   1          0
A        Germany  2010  ...........
A        Austria  2011
B        Italy    2010
```

Also, how would I be able to then add new columns to df1 transforming these counts into dummy variables (1 if >0; 0 if 0)?

Thanks and sorry for this basic question, but I did not find a fitting solutions in existing threads.

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using aggregate() and ifelse() functions

```
# test data
df <- data.frame(Company = rep("A", 3), 
                 Country = rep("Austria", 3), 
                 Year = rep(2010, 3), 
                 JointVenture = c(1,0,1), 
                 MnA = c(0,1,0), 
                 Greenfield = rep(0,3))
# this is the new df
counts <- aggregate(cbind(JointVenture, MnA, Greenfield)~Country+Company+Year, data = df, FUN = sum)

# dummy
counts$dummyJointVenture <- ifelse(counts$JointVenture > 0, 1, 0)
counts$dummyMnA <- ifelse(counts$MnA > 0, 1, 0)
counts$dummyGreenfield <- ifelse(counts$Greenfield > 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: as an aside, this will become tedious with larger data for the dummy part.

Comment: @zacdav yeah, that's a good point. I wasn't considering about the size of the data. your input with choubi would be a better implementation for larger datasets.

Comment: @carlo - thanks, I tried the aggregate() argument:

aggregatedbyguo <- aggregate(cbind(acquisition.dum, ipo.dum, capincrease.dum, jv.dum, merger.dum, fdi.dum)~guo+country.iso+year, data = totaldat_filtered, FUN = sum)

to aggregate by guo, country.iso and year. However, I get values that are not correct (for instance, for a case with only one acquisition, i get value of  3 for acquisition.dum and 2 for all the others).

Any idea what is wrong about my code?

Regards, Martin

Comment: @Martin, for that particular combination of guo, country.iso, and year, could you do the following to check that there is indeed only one case of acquisition

Let df be your data frame.:   
`caseOfInterest <- (guo == guoOfInterest & country.iso == countryOfInterest & year == yearOfInterest) ; 
df[caseOfInterest, ] `

This will check the number of cases for that combination. It could be the case that, if the data is not sorted, the observations of interest are somewhere down the data. Let me know, I'm interested to see if my code is not generalizable. -carlo

Comment: @carlo Thanks for your help! I worked a bit with the original code, and it seems that the problem was that R looked at the variable as factor and not as numeric. I corrected for this now, and it seems to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I throw my `data.table` attempt into the arena:

```
df <- fread("Company  Country  Year
             A        Austria  2010
             A        Germany  2010
             A        Austria  2011
             B        Italy    2010")

df2 <- fread("Company  Country  Year  JointVenture  M&A  Greenfield
              A        Austria  2010  1             0    0
              A        Austria  2010  0             1    0
              A        Austria  2010  1             0    0")

setkey(df2, Company, Country, Year)
df2[,c("JointVenture", "M&A", "Greenfield") := .(sum(JointVenture), sum(`M&A`), sum(Greenfield)), by=.(Company, Country, Year)]
merge(x=df, y=unique(df2), by=c("Company", "Country", "Year"), all.x=T, all.y=F, suffixes = c("", "Count."))
```

Which results in

```
   Company Country Year JointVenture M&A Greenfield
1:       A Austria 2010            2   1          0
2:       A Austria 2011           NA  NA         NA
3:       A Germany 2010           NA  NA         NA
4:       B   Italy 2010           NA  NA         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr::summarise_each` and `merge` with Martin's data.

```
df <- fread("Company  Country  Year
             A        Austria  2010
             A        Germany  2010
             A        Austria  2011
             B        Italy    2010")

df2 <- fread("Company  Country  Year  JointVenture  MA  Greenfield
              A        Austria  2010  1             0    0
              A        Austria  2010  0             1    0
              A        Austria  2010  1             0    0")
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  group_by(Company, Country, Year) %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum), JointVenture:Greenfield) %>%
full_join(df, by = c("Company", "Country", "Year")) -> df
```

edits: replaced a `summarise` with a `summarise_each` with input from @zacdav and replace the `merge` by `full_join` to stay in `dplyr`

Comment: `summarise_each(funs(sum), JointVenture:Greenfield)`

Comment: @zacdav Thanks! I added this solution instead as it scales better